# How to access to a localhost from another machine in the same network?

Tags: networking, localhost, wamp

I have 3 machines connected in the same network. in the first machine i made my localhost server wih wamp 2.2.
I want to access to this server from the other machines (by typing the ip adress on the adress bar of my navigator) but it show an error message.

> Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server
>   i modified the apache file httpd.conf on this :

```
<Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I tried to desactivate my antivirus firewall on the 2 machines but its the same issue.
what should i do ?

Edit 1 : i update wampserver to the version 3.1.0 and maodified the httpd.conf file to

```
    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
# Order deny,allow
Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Now i have access to wampserver homepage from another machine but i can't access to phpMyadmin page.

Edit2 :  i found the solution , i have to modify the phpmyadmin.conf file to allow access from other computers.
you can find the file in the alias folder.

```
  <Directory "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.7.4/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        #Require local
    </ifDefine>
    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        #Order Deny,Allow


    Allow from ALL
    </ifDefine>

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Comment: WAMP 2.2? If you mean WAMPServer 2.2 that is now so old it is no longre supporter

Comment: yes i update it to wampserver 3.1.0 and now i have access to wampserver HomePage but i can't access to PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Are you trying to access phpMyAdmin from the PC running WAMPServer or some other PC on the network

Comment: @RiggsFolly its from another PC on the same network

Comment: finaly i found the solution actually you need to modify the phpmyadmin.conf file (you found it on the alias folder) to allow access from other machines.